# Gnome-Shell no longer a login menu selection

Tags: gnome

I am running Gnome 3 on top of an Ubuntu 11.04 install.  everything had been running fine, but some updates I applied required my rebooting the box to finish the install.  upon restarting everything came up fine, except gnome-shell is no longer in the selection list at the login dialog.  if i log into either unity or gnome classic, i can do open a shell and run gnome-shell --replace, and things are back to how i had them.  i just don't understand what may have happened to cause this?.  any ideas, or is the unity community just mad folk are switching to gnome 3 away from unity and they are trying to make things a bit more difficult:)

either way, thanks for any help that can be afforded

tom

Answer (score 1):

Up to what i know there has been several posts about Ubuntu 11.04 not supporting Gnome 3 (Gnome-Shell). Am guessing this is something you will have to deal yourself as a pioneer of this problem and then later tell us about your findings.

Answer (score 1):

run:

```
echo "export XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-">>$HOME/.profile
```

logout and login